# Why does `perl -i -p0e <expression>` work, but not `perl -0 -pie <expression>`?

Tags: regex, perl

If I try `perl -pie 's/foo/bar/' file.txt` it works as expected: the find-replace expression is executed, and the result is saved to the original file.

However, if I want to use the `-0` to run an expression that includes newlines, simply prepending the option doesn't work:

```
$ perl -0 -pie 's/foo\nbar/qux/' file.txt
Can't open perl script "s/foo\nbar/qux/": No such file or directory
```

After several attempts, the following combination worked:

```
$ perl -i -p0e 's/foo\nbar/qux/' file.txt
```

My question is: why does the first order of options produce an error (especially when plain `-pie` works as expected), while the second ordering is correctly handled?

Comment: `-pie` shouldn't work.

Comment: `perl -0 -pie` means `perl -0 -p -i e`, i.e. the extension `e` for the backup. `perl -i -p0e` instead means `perl -i -p -0 -e`, i.e. no backup since the optional argument to `-i` is missing.

Comment: I always give `-i` separately, and `-0` as well (which should be `-0777`).

Comment: Oh, wow. I'm embarrassed -- I was quite sure `perl -pie` did work, but indeed it errors the same way. I must have mistaken the mnemonic for the actual command :/

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, Not quite. `-ie` can't be written as `-i e`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `-i` means work in-place without backup.
- `-ie` means work in-place, with backup. The backup has the same name as the original file, but with `e` appended.

That means that `perl -pie 's/foo/bar/' file.txt` didn't work either (unless you have a Perl file named `s/foo/bar/`).

If you simply arrange the options logically, you avoid the problem. `-i` has nothing to do with the program —it'll still work if added/removed— so it makes more sense to place it first anyway. `-p` and `-0777`, otoh, are part of the program, so it makes sense to place them next to `-e`. So writing the command sensibly results in one of the following:

```
perl -i  -0777pe'...' ...
perl -i~ -0777pe'...' ...
perl     -0777pe'...' ...
```

Note that I used `-0777`, since `-0` treats the input as NUL-terminated lines rather than activating slurp mode.

Comment: You're right -- the `-pie` option did not work, as the comments above made me realize, and I was considering deleting this question as it was clearly misguided. But since you took the time to write an answer (and a quite informative one at that), I'll accept it instead. Thanks!